# Tracking duplicate keys STL map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, duplicates

I'm trying to write a code using STL map that read and parse the line from a file. How can I track the duplicates in the file? The key values are term and section. I'm thinking to put the duplicates in a vector, but I'm not too sure how. Or is there any better way?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  map <string, map <string, int> > subjectCourse;
  vector <string> duplicate;

  // for parsing the input file
  char* token;
  char buf[1000];
  const char* const tab = "\t";

 // open the input file
 ifstream fin;
 fin.open("schedule.txt");
 clock_t startTime = clock(); // start timer
 if (!fin.good()) throw "I/O error";

 while (fin.good())
 {
  // read line
  string line;
  getline(fin, line);
  strcpy(buf, line.c_str());
  if (buf[0] == 0) continue;

  // parse line
  const string term(token = strtok(buf, tab));
  const string section(token = strtok(0, tab));
  const string course((token = strtok(0, tab)) ? token : "");
  const string instructor((token = strtok(0, tab)) ? token : "");
  const string whenWhere( (token = strtok(0, tab)) ? token : "");
  if (course.find('-') == string::npos) continue; // invalid line
  const string subjectCode(course.begin(), course.begin() + course.find('-'));
  subjectCourse[subjectCode][course]++; // enter data to the map
}

fin.close();

for(map<string, map<string, int> >::iterator i = subjectCourse.begin(); i!= subjectCourse.end(); ++i){
cout << (*i).first << ", " << (*i).second.size() << " courses.\n";
  for(map<string, int>::iterator j = (*i).second.begin(); j != (*i).second.end(); ++j)
    cout << "   " << (*j).first << ", " << (*j).second << " class(es).\n";
}
```

Comment: If all you want is duplicate-detection, a single map of keys-to-int would suffice. During enum, if `++mymap[key] > 1` yields true, you have a duplicate.

Comment: what do you mean? So I also need to track the number of all data other than the duplicates?

Comment: No, i mean if all you care about is duplicate detection, you can forgo value persistence and just use a counter-map for what are supposed to be unique keys. If you want to know about duplicate detection at *insert* time for collections you want to *keep*, utilizing the result of [`std::map<>::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), in particular the `std::pair<>` that contains an iterator to the keyed value *and* a `bool` indicating whether the item was a new insertion, is likely more up the path you want to take. And by the sound of it, you somewhat need *both*.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you need is [std::multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a [multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  multimap <string, string> subjectCourse;
  vector <string> duplicate;

    // for parsing the input file
  char* token;
  char buf[1000];
  const char* const tab = "\t";

    // open the input file
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("schedule.txt");
    clock_t startTime = clock(); // start timer
    if (!fin.good()) throw "I/O error";

    while (fin.good())
    {
    // read line
      string line;
      getline(fin, line);
      strcpy(buf, line.c_str());
      if (buf[0] == 0) continue;

    // parse line
      const string term(token = strtok(buf, tab));
      const string section(token = strtok(0, tab));
      const string course((token = strtok(0, tab)) ? token : "");
      const string instructor((token = strtok(0, tab)) ? token : "");
      const string whenWhere( (token = strtok(0, tab)) ? token : "");
    if (course.find('-') == string::npos) continue; // invalid line
    const string subjectCode(course.begin(), course.begin() + course.find('-'));
    subjectCourse.insert(std::make_pair(subjectCode, course)); // enter data to the map
  }

  fin.close();

  for(multimap<string, string>::iterator i = subjectCourse.begin(); i!= subjectCourse.end(); ++i)
  {
    cout << " " << i->first << " course, " << i->second << " class(es).\n";
  }
}
```

http://ideone.com/Zrf7RO

The only gain is code simplification (no more container of container).

If you want the number of classes for each course:

```
 multimap<string, string>::iterator it = subjectCourse.begin();
 while (it != subjectCourse.end())
 {
   multimap<string, string>::iterator next_it = subjectCourse.upper_bound(it->first);
   cout << " " << it->first << " course as " << std::distance(it, next_it) << " class(es).\n";
   it = next_it;
 }
```

And if you want to track count of duplicates:

```
multimap<string, string>::iterator it = subjectCourse.begin();
while (it != subjectCourse.end())
{
  multimap<string, string>::iterator next_it = it;
  while ((subjectCourse.end() != next_it) 
         && (*it == *next_it))
  {
    ++next_it;
  }

  cout << " " << it->first << " course, " << it->second << " classes: " << std::distance(it, next_it) << " occurences.\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/AqggCV

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to track the number of duplicates. There are two key values here and most examples I look only compare a single key value.

Comment: @chipunpui mmmh, yes and no. You have to count them but they are in the multimap. I've added an example.